# tablesorter & Jquery sorting prices with INR currency not working

Tags: jquery

My question concerns the Jquery plugin Tablesorter :

I've a problem with the sorting of a columns with prices, formatted like that : ₹135.35 INR, ₹149.99 INR etc.

The sorting works well with the sorting of a columns with prices, formatted like that : $135.35 USD, $149.99 USD etc.

please check it http://ehostify.com/ssl-certificates/

As you can see there's something wrong. Can someone please tell me what should i do here?

Thank you very much.

The JS:

```
`$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('.ssl-certi table').tablesorter();
});`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer:

tablesorter.js has code at line 903:

```
ts.addParser({
        id: "currency",
        is: function (s) {
            return /^[£$€?.]/.test(s);
        }, format: function (s) {
            return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(new RegExp(/[£$€]/g), ""));
        }, type: "numeric"
    });
```

change above code with

```
 ts.addParser({
        id: "currency",
        is: function (s) {
            return /^[£$€₹?.]/.test(s);
        }, format: function (s) {
            return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(new RegExp(/[£$€₹]/g), ""));
        }, type: "numeric"
    });
```